# Importing utf8 characters to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV into a MYSQL database. My CSV contains utf8 characters like â when I import these to my database they are replaced with ? marks.

I have tried the following:

a) Importing directly through PHPMYADMIN
b) Importing via Navicat (importing as UTF8)
c) Changing the encoding to UTF8 with open office / mac excel 2010 (seems to make them question marks as well)
d) Saving as CSV ms-dos (not sure if it would make a difference or not)

Can anyone shed some light on what I could be doing wrong? Is it something to do with my Collation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805029/stored-non-english-characters-got-mysql-character-set-issue/29810725#29810725 for a discussion of question marks and how to deal with them.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to check:

1) Make sure your collation for the table and/or rows is utf8_general_ci (for case insensitive) or utf8_bin (for binary exact). There are many others but in my experience one of these two is most common.

2) Make sure your php code files are encoded as UTF-8 Without Byte Order Mark (BOM). This prevents PHP from losing the encoding in-code.

3) If you're using the multibyte functions in php, ensure you have default_charset = "utf-8" set in php.ini

4) Ensure your database connection (probably a setting in phpmyadmin, not certain as I don't use it) is calling mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection); just after you open the connection, and before sending queries.

Comment: Regarding point 4, I guess i have to make sure the data is at least storing as UTF8 before needing to do that part right?

Comment: Yep. They're listed more-or-less in order of importance. Or at least that's the order I check them in when I have to do this. (I run a bunch of sites that handle international search queries so get this issue a lot).

Comment: I set my collation to utf8_general_ci for the database and that particular field. I don't get a question mark in the database anymore its just leaving the letter out all together :(

Comment: Also make sure in your case that the CSV really is UTF8 (if it's output from something like excel on a western-language windows OS it's probably ansi-something), and that whatever you're using to read from the database is actually reading and returning utf8. There's no conversion I know of that will strip characters altogether (most will give you a pair of unusual single-byte chars instead of a multibyte one). The stripping sounds like a problem related to output or some extra processing you or your software may be doing like cleaning with a regex or an incorrect content-encoding header.

Comment: Tried importing from phpmyadmin and navicat still none with the correct result. Tried saving out a couple of files from different programs as UTF just in case. Also tried importing the whole CSV as a UTF table with no luck. Could it perhaps be a MYSQL config issue?

Comment: I doubt it's a mysql config issue (though I don't know all settings) if utf8_general_ci (or similar) is set on the table AND the column to use utf8 it should be fine. It may be worth double-checking what is actually stored in the database using the commandline, because the removal of special-chars still sounds like an output issue rather than a storage issue to me.

Comment: My table and my row was utf8, but not my db ! I changed it to utf8, and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is to do with your collation. You need to change it to a utf8_* collation.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the character set in the import statement worked for me:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/usr/share/mysql/file.csv' 
       INTO TABLE Table1
       CHARACTER SET utf8;
```