# Stored non-English characters, got '?????' - MySQL Character Set issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

My site that I am working on is in Farsi and all the text are being displayed as ????? (question marks).
I changed the collation of my DB tables to UTF8_general_ci but it still shows ???

I ran the following script to change all the tables but this did not work as well.

I want to know what am I doing wrong

```
<?php
// your connection
mysql_connect("mysql.ord1-1.websitesettings.com","user_name","pass");
mysql_select_db("895923_masihiat");

// convert code
$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $table)
    {
        mysql_query("ALTER TABLE " . $table . " CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci");
        echo $key . " =&gt; " . $table . " CONVERTED<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want to know what you're doing wrong: read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Then realize that there's a lot in play: DB collation, table collation, DB connection charset (`mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");`), webpage charset (meta-tags and/or http headers), possibly (PHP) source file encoding etc. **Each** of these need to be correct for everything to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news.  But first, double check:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col)...
```

to see what is in the table.  If the hex shows `3F`, then the data is gone.  Correctly stored, the `dal` character should be hex `D8AF`; `hah` is hex `D8AD`.

What happened:

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

As you `INSERTed` the data, it was converted to latin1, which does not have values for Farsi characters, so question marks replaced them.

The cure (for future `INSERTs):

- Recode your application using mysqli_* interface instead of the deprecated mysql_* interface.
- utf8-encoded data (good)
- mysqli_set_charset('utf8')
- check that the column(s) and/or table default are `CHARACTER SET utf8`
- If you are displaying on a web page, `<meta...utf8>` should be near the top.

The discussion above is about `CHARACTER SET`, the encoding of characters.  Now for a tip on `COLLATION`, which is used for comparing and sorting.

If you want these to be treated equal: 'بِسْمِ' = 'بسم', then use utf8_unicode_ci (instead of utf8_general_ci) for the `COLLATION`.

Comment: @RobIII - good link.  That seems to cover _one_ failure case.  I have identified 4 cases [in my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll) and have ways to repair two of them.  JFA's case is one of two for which the data is lost.