# Displaying data from mysql written in arab

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I add data with HeidiSQL in my table MYSQL `INSERT INTO`proveille`.`sentiments`(`name`,`type`) VALUES ('السلام', 1);`

but in my interface haidiSQL I get this [image]

and all my table

[image]

when I went get this data I used this code PHP

```
$re="select * from sentiments where id=4851";
$sentimentsre=$acc->Select($re);
while ($sentiment = $sentimentsre->fetch()) 
{
    echo $sentiment['name'];
    exit();
}
```

My output in chrome is `?????`

How can I get my true value `السلام`?

English is not my native language.

Comment: What is the encoding in your database? What is the encoding in your web page?

Comment: encoding  database `utf8_genaral` encoding php `header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Question marks?  Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805029/stored-non-english-characters-got-mysql-character-set-issue/29810725#29810725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be MySQL fiddling with your input, check the database if it is storing the data as you intend to.

SELECT * FROM sentiments;

I believe you would need to set the collation type on your table definitions in mysql. Also you would need to set the same encoding type on the transport protocol between PHP and MySQL.